# Show alert when focusout, only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a little problem with my script below. I'm trying to create a script where you can write some text in an input field, and when you have typed some text, you will get an alert when focus-out. The alert should only show, if the input contain text.

But the problem is, that if you're trying to write some text, delete it and then focus-out of the input, the alert do not show next time, when you actually have written something and then focus-out.

Right now, the alert function always will "disappear" when focus out, no matter if you have written any thing or not.

I have tried to add a `var already_alert_me_once = true` before the alert, and then put everything inside an: `if(already_alert_me_once == false`), but that didn't do the trick.

I have also tried to change `$('#title').focusout(function()` with `$('#title').one('focusout', function()` which almost did the trick.

Here is my current script:

```
// When focus on title


 $('#title').focus(function () {
    // Check if empty
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        $('#title').one('focusout', function () {
            if ($(this).val()) {
                alert("YEP");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

..and [Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T7tFd/3/)

So my question is; How to I do so the alert only appears when you **have** written something, and after that never again *(unless you reload the page)*.

Hope you can understand what I mean.

Thanks - TheYaXxE

Comment: Typo, should say `on` not `one`

Comment: @TomStyles `one` means it only gets triggered once.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rkumar670/T7tFd/6/

Comment: Learning everyday. Thanks for the correction @Archer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pretty much the easiest solution, no need for .one or focus events :)

```
$('#title').blur(function() {
    if( $(this).val() ) {
        alert('!!');
        $(this).unbind('blur');
    } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T7tFd/5/

Comment: Also a great solution! I choose this because it's the easiest solution, as you are telling yourself :)

Answer (score 3):

You can unbind the focus using:

```
$('#title').unbind('focus');
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T7tFd/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

instead of putting the variable "already_alert_me_once" inside the function, make it a global variable. that way the scope will be maintained. you could also add an attribute to the #title that indicates that it has already been clicked, then check to see if that attribute exists before executing the code.